# Linking Application Settings(created using Application Preference) from Application

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I want to Link my Application Settings(created using Application Preferences) from button inside Application, i.e. when button is pressed can we Open Application Settings.

Help Needed ASAP.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not open the settings application from you're own code.